# Fix an element inside an iframe in the center of the screen

Tags: css, facebook, iframe

I have an iframe embedded inside a fan page of FB, and I want to show a fixed box (like a dialog box) at the center of the screen.

How can I do that?

#### UPDATE

Look at Work For Us app:

http://www.facebook.com/DiscoverIntel?ref=nf&sk=app_404596412628

[image]

When I click in the green button behind (named "Apply for this position") it always shows the "Thank you" dialog at the center of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got the same problem today. The solution is you just need to get scroll position of the viewport from the parent of the iframe which is Facebook URL. So, Facebook has provided JavaScript SDK for it already.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.getPageInfo/

You can use clientHeight, clientWidth , scrollTop and scrollLeft to calculate the center position.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `iframe` fills a `div` element that's `position` style is set to `relative`. It's impossible and for good reason too. What if the center of the screen isn't over your `iframe`? Facebook doesn't want you doing anything crazy and messing with the presentation of the page itself (i.e. hiding advertisements, making a fake Facebook-looking elements, etc.).

But if you are looking to center an element within the `iframe`, you can do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Centering an element with CSS</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #center_container {
                left: 50%;
                position: fixed;
                top: 50%;
            }
            #center {
                border: 1px dashed #000; /* added to show size and position of element */
                height: 100px;
                left: -100px; /* -0.5 * width */
                position: absolute;
                top: -50px; /* -0.5 * height */
                width: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="center_container">
            <div id="center">This tag is centered.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, you will have to stick to using JavaScript's [popup box functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp): `alert()`, `confirm()`, and `prompt()`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the Intel page is not yours and you want to mimic that popup box, correct?

Comment: Yes, Intel page install Work For Us app. And the app is have this feature. I want to mimic this feature for me.

Comment: Wow, I looked at the source and it looked pretty intense. If you are determined to get this functionality, you will need a vast knowledge of JavaScript and a decent amount of how jQuery works. After that, I'd use Chrome and inspect the three script elements in the iframe (primarily the second and third), and then look at the event listeners for the green button itself. It's not anything (IMHO) that can be quick fixed. It will take a good bit of reading uncommented code. Basically, it looks like they made a `Dialog` "class" in JavaScript are instantiating it to make that dialog box.