# how to get fancybox centered in facebook iframe app

Tags: facebook, iframe, fancybox

I'm trying to get Fancybox to center up on the screen within a facebook iframe app. Everything works fine on my test page outside of FB but once I put it in my app it shows up centered according to the iframe height not the viewable screen. I have also noticed that the `'centerOnScroll': true` is also ignored when using inside FB app. Any suggestions would be great and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Centering in a iframe according to it's viewable height is generally not workable. Have a look at the following answer.

[Fix an element inside an iframe in the center of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061728/fix-an-element-inside-an-iframe-in-the-center-of-the-screen)